# Verify if a customer already opted out to be deleted

Tags: leads, gdpr

Is there a way/place/functionality where you can verify if a customer already opted out to delete the data from Salesforce? to avoid recreating it again.
Example: a Lead requests that his data is deleted from our Salesforce system, we delete it. After some time someone wants to create a new Lead, but we already had that Lead in to our system. And to avoid GDPR problems it would be nice to have some sort of Black Box where we can search for already deleted Leads?

I remember some while ago someone mentioned something like this, and that it was GDPR compliant, but I don't remember exactly the name, or if is something available in Salesforce or something custom made.

Do you know if something like this exists?

Answer (score 1):

If the user re-engages with your business thereby creating a Lead, you are not obligated to ignore it. With GDPR you have to remove their info when requested but that's a point in time removal. Any future interaction is fair game.

Comment: I understand if the customer re-engages with us is OK. But if the customer requested to delete his data, and after a while one of our sales agents stable on his email address via a recommendation or something. How can we know if we already had that customer and he opted out?

Comment: Without tracking him, which you can't do, you can't know that he already opted out. You have to have a solid system for removal (documented!) and trust that system.